# <div><a /></div> instead of <button />?

Tags: html, css

I've inherited an existing website to maintain and upgrade.

One of the site's quirks is how it does buttons.

It has html like this:

```
<div class="btn">
    <a id="dv_remCont" runat="server" href="#" onclick="removeContact();">remove contact</a>
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
div.btn a {
        font-weight:bold;
        display:inline-block;
        border-radius: 2px;
        padding: 0 1.2em 0 1.2em;
        color:#ffffff;
        background-color:black;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #898986, inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), 0px 0px 1px 1px #000000;
    }
div.btn a:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #898986, inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), 0px 0px 1px 1px #000000;
}
```

This creates a clickable button. It does cause some complications, though - not using a regular `<button />` means default functionality for stuff like forms doesn't work. Also, there are some issues with alignment in IE8 and below.

What are the advantages of doing buttons like this? Have you seen them done in this style before?

Comment: `<a runat="server">`? What system is it built on?

Comment: asp.net, but that's not really relevant here. Basically its just anchors shoved inside div tags, and then the anchors styled to make things that look like buttons.

Comment: I guess that has something to do with jQuery (javascript). http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers

Comment: I don't see advantage for anchor type buttons if they're inside a form. If they're outside a form, then yes.

Comment: Check the original code in asp. Usually it has similar button declarations which are interpreted at runtime http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/ASPNET1/ASPNET03/aspnet03-02.aspx

Comment: We use mootools rather than jquery, but I don't see how that could be related. Surely it's possible to use `button` elements the same way as `a` elements?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that it's easier to align them next to other `inline` (`inline-block`) items, as opposed to `<button>`s

Comment: Links are easier to style consistently than buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of no specific reason to do this - other than the developer not being able to quite reset the button style to nothing before creating the custom style.

For example, even if you reset all padding, border, background, margin - the button still doesn't quite look unstyled in Firefox 3.6 or IE 7 or 8 - which if you've inherited the code are probably the target browsers when it was being written.

This is an example you can use to play with - I have added a border reset to the style to make the button and fake button look closer, You would also have to add text-decoration: underline if you want it to look exactly the same, but I couldn't bring myself to have a button that already looks clickable include an underline!

http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/7Eakq/1/

Comment: Thanks for the input, this is very helpful. I really started to run into problems with these kinds of buttons when trying to have different font for the text on the button to the surrounding text - it's hard to get the vertical alignment right.